# How to get specific timezone datetime value using momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a Event Created datetime value in DB which is actually time corresponding to "America" while entered.

And i want check if the event is already expired in `client side javascript` and i'm using `momentjs`

The catch is how will i  check the expired event properly if i'm in a different time zone (for ex: india).

```
var eventDate = "05/06/2014 12:38 AM"
moment(eventDate).diff(moment())
```

instead of `moment()` how can i get moment object of specific time zone?

UPDATED
http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Need to include  moment timezone js file and try below code

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a")
```

Comment: Docs?  http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

You can force eventDate to be formatted in a specific timezone:

`var eventDate = "05/06/2014 12:38 AM GMT-0400"` would result in `moment(eventDate)` offset to the local timezone.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4hQ2/